# How to add image/video to a specific object on loaded scene from Blender

Tags: three.js

I have a scene imported from Blender. I have a few screens inside the scene and I would like to add either an image/video on those screens.

[image: screenshot of the actual scene]

Note: *I'm using the OOP model to create the app*

I have the scene imported with the gltfLoader and I wait for all the resources to be loaded

```
 this.resources.on('ready', () => {

            // Setup
            this.controlRoom = new ControlRoom()
            this.tvScreen4x4 = new tvScreen4x4()

        })
```

ControlRoom is the actual scene and the other one is just one mesh from all the screens.

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
import Experience from "../../Experience.js"

export default class tvScreen4x4 {

    constructor() {
        this.experience = new Experience()
        this.scene = this.experience.scene
        this.resources = this.experience.resources

        // Setup
        this.setTexture()
        this.setMaterial()
        this.updateMesh()
    }

    setTexture() {
        this.texture = {}
        this.texture.normal = this.resources.items.tvScreen4x4
    }

    setMaterial() {
        this.material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
            map: this.texture.normal
        })
    }

    updateMesh() {

        this.scene.traverse((child) => {
            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh && child.name === 'tv_4x4_screen') {

                child.material = this.material
                child.material.needsUpdate = true

                console.log(child.material);

            }
        })
    }
}
```

```
this.resources.items.tvScreen4x4
```

Is returning this the item from my custom source.js

```
export default [
    {
        name: 'controlRoom',
        type: 'gltfModel',
        path: 'models/controlroom.gltf'
    },
    {
        name: 'tvScreen4x4',
        type: 'texture',
        path: 'textures/screen.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'tvScreen5x4',
        type: 'texture',
        path: 'textures/screen.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'tvScreen6x4',
        type: 'texture',
        path: 'textures/screen.jpg'
    }
]
```

The console.log(child.material) returns the following:

[image]

[image]

What I am doing wrong that the texture doesn't show on that screen? The console log returns the correct map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the fix for my issue. The code was correct and the scene was imported as it should. One thing I haven't done right is how I exported the Blender scene.

When exporting the scene i should have ticked the UVs and in the Geometry section. Like below.
[image]

So it was more of a blender issue rather than a Three.js

Answer (score 0):

Load the texture, apply the texture to the object you want, then add the model to the scene:

```js
const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(imageUrl);

new GLTFLoader().load(modelUrl, (gltf) => {
  gltf.scene.traverse((object) => {
    if (object.isMesh && object.name === "SCREEN") {
      object.material.map = texture;
    }
  });
  scene.add(gltf.scene);
});
```

Demo:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
  import * as THREE from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/build/three.module.js";
  import { OrbitControls } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
  import { GLTFLoader } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";
  import { DRACOLoader } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/examples/jsm/loaders/DRACOLoader.js";

  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  const cameraMin = 0.0001;

  const aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspect, cameraMin, 1000);
  const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const model =
    "https://vazxmixjsiawhamofees.supabase.co/storage/v1/object/public/models/iphone-x/model.gltf";

  const image =
    "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/colorful-umbrellas-for-sale-in-luang-prabang-laos-picture-id918965792";

  const loader = new GLTFLoader();
  const dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader();
  dracoLoader.setDecoderPath(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/js/libs/draco/"
  );
  loader.setDRACOLoader(dracoLoader);

  const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(image);

  loader.load(model, (gltf) => {
    gltf.scene.traverse((object) => {
      if (!object.isMesh) return;
      if (object.name === "SCREEN") {
        object.material.map = texture;
        // console.log(object);
      }
    });
    const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(gltf.scene);
    const center = box.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());
    gltf.scene.position.x += gltf.scene.position.x - center.x;
    gltf.scene.position.y += gltf.scene.position.y - center.y;
    gltf.scene.position.z += gltf.scene.position.z - center.z;
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
  });

  camera.position.z = 5;

  const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight();
  scene.add(ambientLight);

  (function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    controls.update();

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Now it works. I'll update below the answer.